# Print many paged pdf-files with multiple images from commandline

Tags: bash, printer, cups

We are using a linux server with cups to print pdf-files from command-line.
This has always worked in the past but recently we added more images to our pdf's and this caused an error. The printer stopt printing after 25 pages of the 400 page file.

We called the supplier of our printer and they said we should use adobe as application and choose `"print as image"` in the advanced print options.

When we do this, all pages are printed correctly.
But we don't want to do this manually each time we have a large pdf-file. We would prefer if cups did this for us or if we could add an extra action in our bash script.

Currently we use this command to print from command line:
`lpr -r -P clx952_duplex_bw -o MediaType=Preprinted -o JCLFrontCoverOption=BlankPreprinted -o JCLFrontCoverType=Color "$pdfFile"`

Is there an easy way to support these bigger pdf's by altering this command or our cups settings?